# Angular2 SVG directive silently failing

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, angular2-directives

I am trying to use the `ng2-inline-svg` plugin with my Angular2 app but is it silently failing.

External template:

`<div class="my-icon" aria-label="My icon" [inlineSVG]="'src/assets/svg/sprite.svg'"></div>`

Reference in component:

`@Component({
      selector: "home",
       styleUrls: [],
      templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
   })`

I can use my chrome inspector to see this

`<div aria-label="My icon" class="my-icon" ng-reflect-inline-s-v-g="src/assets/svg/sprite.svg"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:absolute; width: 0; height: 0">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="icon-plus">
       ...
    </symbol>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 77 100" id="icon-edit">
        ...
    </symbol>
</svg></div>`

in the inspector but it is not displaying on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue was actually with the styling on my svg and not the plugin.

For example, this file worked:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100" width="100">
  <g transform="translate(0,-952.36216)">
    <path transform="translate(0,952.36216)" d="M 40 0 L 40 40 L 0 40 L 0 60 L 40 60 L 40 100 L 60 100 L 60 60 L 100 60 L 100 40 L 60 40 L 60 0 L 40 0 z " />
  </g>
</svg>`

If you look at the end of the `svg` tag you can see where is defined the height and the width, whereas in the original `svg` I posted it has height and width set to zero.